# Multithread Form Application (.NET 4.0)

Tags: multithreading, forms, .net-4.0

I'm currently working on a solution that has two projects, a console and a form application.  The console application is the main entry point to my application, and from the console the user would run the form application.

The problem is, when the user boots the form application the rest of the business logic (from the console app) won't run until the form is closed.  My first thought was to use a background worker for the form, but the business logic in the form project already uses a background worker (and I only have two CPUs...).   Perhaps this could be my ignorance for multithreading, but is there a way to do this?

Any thoughts are much appreciated!
Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this is pretty unusual.  In general, it doesn't make a lot of sense to provide the user with a nice GUI and still leave a console window up and interactive.

But yes, calling Application.Run() or Form.ShowDialog() is going to block the thread.  It has to, the message loop needs to be running to keep the GUI alive.  If you do this, be sure to put the [STAThread] attribute on the Main() method.

The only other decent alternative is to start a thread.  This isn't a problem, a UI thread doesn't burn any CPU cycles.  Code only ever runs when the user does something, it's otherwise idle 99% of the time.  Be sure to call the thread's SetApartmentState() method before you start it, STA is required.

Comment: Thanks Hans.  I'm a bit of a beginner when it comes to things like this, but how would I start another thread and set that SetApartmentState().  And would starting another thread like this conflict with the backgroundworker that is created further in the business logic?

Comment: Well, it certainly could.  If the form is also running business logic code that touches objects that the BGW is touching as well then you need to lock.  I'd have to recommend going slow here, threading is hard to get right.  Ditch the console first.

Comment: Hmm...  The console is basically where the user writes command (sort of like mySQL command window).  The form is really for the user to see what the backgroundworker is doing (the BGW is running an endless loop pulling data and writing / sending it back to the rest of the business logic).  As of now, the BGW writes to the console what its doing, but then that kills the user's ability to write commands. [Basically the idea of the program is that the BGW will always have most recent data available, and main business logic allows user to pull material related to that data instantly]...

Comment: Or would a WPF application allow for something like this?  I just want something to display incoming data...

Comment: A text box can also display scrolling text.  Use the BGW's ReportProgress() method.

Comment: Yup, thats the method I'm using. How could I use a textbox though? (the 'progress' I'm reporting isn't a standard % value, but is a bunch of data.  Could a textbox also support this?)